Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test in R and/or Python, how to find degrees of freedom?
I am trying to run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov/K-S test in R using the ks.test() function, and I am trying to find the degrees of freedom when comparing across two different groups. I am also trying in Python using the ks_2samp function from the scipy package. I can successfully run these functions and get a test statistic and a p-value, but I am wondering if there is a way to find the degrees of freedom. The sample sizes of the two groups are different. I am new to statistics, so any help would be appreciated.

Well, not only ks.test() does not have degrees of freedom, but generally speaking, afaik, Kolmogoroff Smirnoff test doesn't neither (the latter explain of course the former). Degrees of freedom are a thing for hypothesis test that tries to check a p-value for a known law. For example, testing if two samples are from the same law use statistics "sum of square difference of effective in each category". Since it can be proven that for a given number of categories, this follow a χ₂ distribution, we use test of the same name.

KS is a more generic test, that tests if two samples follow the same distribution. It compares continuous data, without the need to bin them into categories. Just out of curiosity: what are you calling "degree of freedom"? Is there some sort of context explaining that, or is it a generic term? Because, usually, we call degree of freedom the number of samples (-1) when we do some variance estimation (with a χ² law also, tho, not a χ² test). Or, in χ² test, the number of bins (-1 also). Or is multinomial adequation test (same. Anyway, a binned adequation is a multinomial).

But I am trying to get in what kind of situation you can look at a dataset, and think "I wonder what the DoF of this dataset is". You can't be wondering how many samples they are. I am sure you know how to get the size of an array. You can't be wondering in how many bins they are categorized: that is an hypothesis you decide to do. Oh, I can think of some situations where "I wonder how many DoF this dataset have" is a question that make sense. For example, is you want to do dimension reduction using PCA, that is a question you are answering (2 dimensions is enough to summarize this data

so, said otherwise, there are 2 DoF). But that is really not related at all with adequation test of 2 samples, and KS.

TL;DR: The probability distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test does not have degrees of freedom parameters. Instead the sample sizes are the parameters of this distribution.
The degrees of freedom in a test such as a $t$ test, $F$ test, or $\chi^2$ test are parameters of the probability distributions associated with these tests. In the case of Student’s $t$ distribution that degrees of freedom parameter characterizes the variance and uncertainty associated with the sample size of Student's $t$ distribution. In the case of the $F$ distribution there are two degrees of freedom, and if you squint at it, the numerator degrees of freedom (very roughly) characterizes the location and shape of the distribution, and the denominator degrees of freedom (very roughly) characterizes the dispersion of the distribution, etc..
The exact probability distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test does not have any such degrees of freedom parameter. Instead, its parameters are the sample sizes (in the two-sample test) or the sample size (in the one-sample test). The distribution itself can be represented by the number of ways you can order observations of $x$ and $y$. For example, if $n_x = 2$ and $n_y = 2$, then these are exactly and only these six possible orderings of values (assuming no ties are possible):

$xxyy$
$xyxy$
$xyyx$
$yxxy$
$yxyx$
$yyxx$

You can see that if you change the sample sizes (i.e. the number of $x$s and/or $y$s), then you will change the number ways to order the values of $x$ and $y$, and therefore change the probability distribution. (Aside: If ties are possible the number of orderings for $n_x = 2$ and $n_y = 2$ would equal $26$.).
There's a nice way to visually represent the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distribution, which is as the possible non-crossing traversals through a rectangular lattice starting from the origin at $(0,0)$, and ending at the point $n_x, n_y$. See Gibbons & Chakraborti, 2010 for a good explanation (the diagonal line corresponds to the null hypothesis of 'same distribution': the larger the maximum vertical or horizontal distance from that line an observed trajectory is, the less likely the samples were to have been drawn from the same distribution):

In the lattice traversal representation the 'with no ties' assumption just means that each trajectory must move only a single unit rightward or a single unit upward for each step of a trajectory. Relaxing that assumption to allow ties means that traversals may contain single steps of multiple units (e.g., a shift of two units rightward or upward), and may contain single steps which move simultaneously in rightward and upward directions. Schröer and Trenkler, 1995 give a good visualization of this kind of lattice traversal:




References
Gibbons, J. D., & Chakraborti, S. (2010). Nonparametric Statistical Inference (5th edition). Chapman & Hall/CRC.
Schröer, G., & Trenkler, D. (1995). Exact and randomization distributions of Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests two or three samples. Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 20, 185–202.

Thank you so much, that's super helpful!

Follow up question. Is the p-value that is produced from a 2 sample KS test impacted by degrees of freedom in the same way that a p-value produced from a t-test is?

@Rachel The K-S test does not have degrees of freedom.
